# How to see who has shared your site with Google Plus or how to view Google Plus metrics and activity?

Tags: google-plus, social-networking

Is there a way to see a list of the people who have shared your site with Google Plus (i.e., the people who have clicked the plus one button for a specific URL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicks to the +1 Button aren't quite the same thing as sharing (for example as part of an activity), but you can indeed see lots of neat data about +1's and your site using Google's Webmaster Tools: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Comment: Hi Jenny.  Does this include metrics from +1's on a google result page?  For instance, I know I can track people +1's when they click the plus one on my site.  However say they click +1 from the Google results page after searching... Can I see those +1's?

Comment: Yup! This includes all +1's to those URLs both from the +1 button and from web search results.

Comment: has this been removed from Google's Webmaster Tools, can't seem to find it and the FAQ url doesn't resolve, is there some other place / resource where I can find +1 info for my site?